# PHP Only add unique value into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm adding data into an array from batch of PLIST files inside a WHILE loop but I have some duplicated PLIST files which I don't want to be added into the array again. so I use this code but still adding duplicated entries.

```
$tmp= array($title, $bundle, $url);
if (!in_array($tmp, $array)) {
array_push($array, $tmp);
}
```

So the output of the $array is something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => SamanBank
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 4.5.0
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => https://example.ir/wRteD2G8Lyk.ipa
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => FiLMiC Pro－Video Camera Hacked
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 6.9.7.1
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => https://example.ir/wRteD23SLgs.ipa
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Noizio — focus, relax, sleep
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 7.2.501
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => https://example.ir/wRteD2G8Afe.ipa
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => SamanBank
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 4.5.0
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => https://example.ir/wRteD2G8Lyk.ipa
                )

        )
```

So the first array is repeated twice. How can I edit the above code to skip pushing the repeated entries into the array?

Comment: Have you tried converting ``SimpleXMLElement`` into an array before checking ``if (!in_array($tmp, $array)) {}``

Comment: No, I didn't. can you explain why it's saved as this and how should I convert please?

Comment: I think maybe your ``in_array`` check is failing because it is an object

Answer (score 0):

Well, As Dula mentioned correctly, the tiny mistake I had within my code was that I didn't convert the Xml to String before pushing to the array.

so the code from:

```
$title= $xml->dict->array->dict->dict->string[3];
```

Should have been changed to:

```
$title= (string)$xml->dict->array->dict->dict->string[3];
```

and now, with

```
if (!in_array($tmp, $array)) {
array_push($array, $tmp);
}
```

I have an unique array!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SamanBank
            [1] => 4.5.0
            [2] => https://example.ir/wRteD2G8Lyk.ipa
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FiLMiC Pro－Video Camera Hacked
            [1] => 6.9.7.1
            [2] => https://example.ir/wRteD23SLgs.ipa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Noizio — focus, relax, sleep
            [1] => 7.2.501
            [2] => https://example.ir/wRteD2G8Afe.ipa
        )
```